# Typescript using the Parameters<> Utility Type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use Parameters<> to imitate a function with a wrapper function.  I thought something like the below would work and I was hoping to understand why it doesn't.  The "spawn" method has overloads, I'm assuming Parameters<> is using the params from the function implementation, ie 1 required and 2 optional params.

```
import { spawn } from "child_process"

function spawnWrapper(...args: Parameters<typeof spawn>) {
    spawn(...args)
    // ...
}

spawn("ls", ["-la"]) // => TS compiler is happy

spawnWrapper("ls", ["-la"]) // => Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.
```

**EDIT**
Example not using an imported function:

```
function foo ( param: string ): void
function foo ( param: number, option: boolean ): void
function foo( param: string | number, option?: boolean ): void {}

function fooBar ( ...args: Parameters<typeof foo> ) {
    foo( ...args )
}

foo( "baz" ) // OK
fooBar( "baz" ) // Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
```

**EDIT #2: Answer from @ABOS**

```
function foo ( param: string ): void
function foo ( param: number, option: boolean ): void
function foo( param: string | number, option?: boolean ): void
function foo( param: string | number, option?: boolean ): void {}

function fooBar ( ...args: Parameters<typeof foo> ) {
    foo( ...args )
}

foo( "baz" ) // OK
fooBar( "baz" ) // OK
```

Comment: when you call `spawn`, it will find the match from all overloaded versions, so 2 args is ok; but when called `spawnWrapper`, `Parameters<typeof spawn>` will use the last overloaded version, hence 3 arguments.

Comment: Does this question depend on `child_process`?  If so, you might want to tag it as such. If not, you might want to remove your example code's dependency on it, by providing the relevant type definitions (and possibly making it a [mre] with just a few overloads where the same error occurs).

Comment: Thanks for the responses! @ABOS I'm not quite sure I get it yet, but I'll dig into it and try to understand how it's using the overload

Comment: @jcalz I thought about writing an overload function, but it seemed like it'd be even simpler with a common function.  I see what you're saying though, I'll add an edit with my own func

Comment: @Sean, this is the doc https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html "When inferring from a type with multiple call signatures (such as the type of an overloaded function), inferences are made from the last signature (which, presumably, is the most permissive catch-all case). It is not possible to perform overload resolution based on a list of argument types."

Comment: @ABOS thanks for the link and the info, I've reread that last sentence about 20 times now trying to make sense of it.  Isn't the "last signature ie the most permissive catch-all" the signature with the optional arg?  That feels like evidence it should be working.  Obviously it doesn't though.  It's unfortunate because the pattern in the example has been pretty handy in JS, and the pattern's not possible in TS, even though logically all the params should be pretty easily inferable. It feels like a bug or limitation of TS.  Maybe I just still don't get it, thanks for trying to help me understand

Comment: @Sean, it is just the way how typescript works, since it is clearly documented, I don't think it is a bug (perhaps an improvement if needed). For your case, just add `function foo( param: string | number, option?: boolean ): void` before the implementation. I should remove the error.

Comment: @ABOS I get it now! Thank you for being patient with me.  I think seeing your code for the last overload and doing more research finally helped it click for me.  I was misunderstanding how overloads work: that they replace the function signature, not add onto it.

Answer (score -1):

According to the IntelliSense box, there are 20 overloads for `spawn`. Here's a link to the lines in the current declaration file:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/122c5336ff41ad8b0e3ebddc4e96e34facaaf8e5/types/node/child_process.d.ts#L650-L789

Also, here's a link to the API docs for the current Node LTS version:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Depending on what exactly you want to support (and what kind of DX you're trying to implement), you'll need to handle fewer or more of the overload cases with your wrapper.

---

If you want to support only the case in your example, you can define a 2-member tuple for the parameters, like this:

```ts
import {spawn} from 'child_process';

function spawnWrapper (...params: [
  Parameters<typeof spawn>[0],
  Parameters<typeof spawn>[1],
]) {
  return spawn(...params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was hoping Parameters<> was going to take the implementation's signature that was compatible with all the functions, it doesn't seem to be working the way I thought it would though.